# Finding force on an object from newton's second law of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Imagine a body of mass "m" inside a box of mass "M".Let us assume that box is moving at a constant velocity.Then an observer from outside would see both the body and box moving. Let us now apply a force F on that object and object accelerated by "a". Now if I want to calculate the force from observers perspective. Which mass should I consider "m" or "M"

Comment: Which Object m or M

Comment: Your question is not clear